# List the films in which 'Harrison Ford' has appeared

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Why is the answer to this question incorrect?

Database

```
movie (id(PK),  title,  yr,     director(FK),   budget,     gross)
actor (id(PK),  name )
casting (movieid(PK, FK),   actorid(PK, FK),    ord)
```

Question: List the films in which 'Harrison Ford' has appeared (original link [here](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations#Harrison_Ford_movies))

My answer:

```
select title
from movie
were id IN
(
    select movieid as id
    from casting
    where actorid IN 
    (
        select id as actorid
        from actor
        where name = 'Harrison Ford'
    )
) X
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: We'd need to see sample data and expected results.

Comment: were != where could be an answer.

Comment: _Why is the answer to this question incorrect?_ How do you know it is incorrect?

Comment: @danblack I solved it with joins. But I wanted to try it without joins. Was wondering why this subquery wont work

Comment: @Abra It shows on the site itself when I run my query   https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations

Comment: @DaleK Here are the details of the DB https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_details_about_the_database. I am trying to solve it with mysql syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After correcting `were` -> `where` and removing the trailing `X` the syntax and result where correct.

```
select title
from movie
where id IN
(
    select movieid as id
    from casting
    where actorid IN 
    (
        select id as actorid
        from actor
        where name = 'Harrison Ford'
    )
)
```

Error message indicated it was using MariaDB

Comment: Thanks @danblack. I think I missed correcting the spelling of where when I was posting this question. The problem actually lied in the trailing X which I removed and now its working

Answer (score 0):

```
    select title from movie inner join casting on (movie.id = casting.movieid)
    inner join actor on (casting.actorid = actor.id)
    where actor.name = 'Harrison Ford'
```

Please use the above SQL code for this question on SQL Zoo; it is in the exercise related to "More Joins". Hence you should be using Joins to solve it

Answer (score 0):

My solution using CTE and `JOIN`:

```sql
-- find the movieid in which Harrison Ford played
WITH t AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT movieid
    FROM actor
    JOIN casting ON actor.id = casting.actorid
    WHERE name = 'Harrison Ford'
)

-- Get the movie title using a simple inner join
SELECT title
FROM movie
JOIN t ON movie.id = t.movieid
```